# Problema al setear 2 valores de acuerdo a una lectura analogica en c++

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy simulando un lector de temperatura leyendo valores de un pin análogo y establezco valores mínimos y máximos mediante el monitor serial.

- vmi: número, para establecer un valor mínimo el cual activara una señal cuando sea igual o este por debajo de dicho valor,
- vma: número, para establecer un valor máximo, el cual activara otra salida si el valor es igual o mayor al establecido.

El problema es que mi programa cuando setea un valor minimo y luego un maximo, este valor maximo puede tomar valores que estan entre los valores minimos y viceverza.
¿Como puedo hacer para que los valores maximos y minimos no puedan ser seteados con valores que le pertenecan al otro?

ejemplo:
si seteo como valor maximo 1000, y luego seteo como valor maximo 500, esto no deberia ser posible.

codigo:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5);
int analogoPin=A8;
float val=0;
float val1=0;
int ventilador=D6;
int calefactor=D7;
String tecla= " ";
String texto= " ";
String num=" ";
String compmi="";
String compma="";
int numi=1;
int numa=0;
int num2=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(calefactor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ventilador, OUTPUT);
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
val=analogRead(analogoPin);
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  texto="";
  num="";
 tecla = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
 char vt[tecla.length()+1];
 tecla.toCharArray(vt, tecla.length()+1);
 for(int i=0; i<tecla.length()+1;i++)
 {
   vt[i]= tolower(vt[i]);
 }


for(int i=0; i<tecla.length()+1;i++)
 {
   if(isalpha(vt[i]))
   {
      texto= texto+ vt[i];

   }
   if(isdigit(vt[i]))
   {
      num= num+ vt[i];
   }

 }

}

 texto.trim();
 num.trim();
 Serial.println(num);



if(texto=="vmi")
{
   if(num.toInt()!=numa)
  {
  
  compmi=texto;
 
    numi=num.toInt();
  }
}

if(texto=="vma")
{
  if(num.toInt()!=numi)
  {
  compma=texto;
  
    numa=num.toInt();
  }

}



if(compmi=="vmi")
{
if(numi<=4095 && numi>=0)
{
if(val<=numi)
{
  digitalWrite(calefactor,1);
  Serial.print("Valor minimo seteado a: ");

}
else
{
  digitalWrite(calefactor,0);

}

}
}

if(compma=="vma")
{
if(numa<=4095 && numa>=0)
{
if(val>=numa)
{
  digitalWrite(ventilador,1);
  Serial.print("Valor maximo seteado a: ");

}
else
{
  digitalWrite(ventilador,0);

}

}
}






lcd.clear();
lcd.print(val,0);
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
val1=(val*3.3/2703);
lcd.print(val1,3);
delay(1000);
delay(1000);

 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está aquí:

```
if(texto=="vmi")
{
  compmi=texto;
  numi=num.toInt();
}
else
{
  numi=0;
}

if(texto=="vma")
{
  compma=texto;
  numa=num.toInt();
}
else
{
  numa=0;
}
```

Las variables solo pueden tomar un único valor a la vez. Si `texto` es `vmi` entonces no es `"vma"`. Por lo tanto `numa = 0` y viceversa.

Quita los `else` y problema solucionado.

Comment: Haora tengo un nuevo problema, cuando seteo un valor maximo  el programa no debe permitirme un valor minimo mayor al valor maximo y viceversa, al momento solo he podido controlar que cuando los valores maximo y minimo sean iguales se mantenga el valor anterior

Comment: he editado mi codigo para que se pueda ver la nueva versión del codigo

Comment: @AxwellDuarte no deberías cambiar la pregunta porque así las respuestas que te dieron dejan de responder a la pregunta.

Comment: @AxwellDuarte con todas las medallas que tiene no creo que seas principiante. Piensalo. Puedes usar una variable adicional que tenga temporalmente el valor recibido y modificar `vmi` y `vma` solo si se cumplen las condiciones necesarias. No es necesario que cargues el código al Arduino para probar la lógica, puedes usar un compilador en línea como https://tio.run/